# Input variables in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with reading variables in one line.  I used a `map(int, input().splite())` when I know the number of variables, but in this case in every run of code this number is different. (Python 3)

Comment: `list(map(int, input().strip().split()))` is this what you want?

Comment: how about code example?

Comment: do you mean `input().split(' ')`, this would take an input like this 'hello Thomas 9 five' and store it in a list like this ['hello', 'Thomas', '9', 'five']

Answer (score 1):

Hi try something like

```
runs = 10 # some value you can inpt with int(input("Enter runs: "))
values = []

for i in range(runs):
    values.append(input("enter the "+str(i)+". variable: "))
```

this creates an array like:

```
["10", "32", "hello", "world", "23", "bye"]
```

but I think there is no way to do this in one line..